# Minimum bracket reversal

Tags: java, stack

Given a string expression which consists only ‘}’ and ‘{‘. The expression may not be balanced. You need to find the minimum number of bracket reversals which are required to make the expression balanced.
Return -1 if the given expression can't be balanced.

Below the code has wrong output on *( input= `}{` )*. My code return -1.But output should be  2.I am unable to understand which of the test case is note included.Please give some suggestion or changes to be done to produce desired output

```
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {

    public static int countBracketReversals(String input){
        Stack<Character> stk=new Stack<>();
        char c1; char c2;
        int c=0;
        int l=input.length();
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i)=='{')
            {
                stk.push(input.charAt(i));
            }
            if(input.charAt(i)=='}')
            {
                if(stk.isEmpty())
                {
                    stk.push(input.charAt(i));
                }
                if(stk.peek()=='{')
                {
                    stk.pop();
                }
                if(stk.peek()=='}')
                {
                    stk.push(input.charAt(i));
                }
            }
          
        }
        int a=stk.size();
        if(a%2==0)
        {
           while(!stk.isEmpty())
         {
            c1= stk.pop();
            c2= stk.pop();
            
            if(c1==c2)
            {
                c=c+1;
            }
            if(c1=='}' && c2=='{')
            {
                c=c+2;
            }
         }
        }
        else
        {
         c=-1;
        }
      return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you process matching brackets when you process the individual brackets, the bracket characters that remain in the stack all need to be reversed. Hence, the output must be the size of the stack `stk.size()`.

There is a bug in your processing code. You must use `else if` and not `if` after checking if the stack is empty without which `stk.peek()` will be called on an empty stack.

```
if(stk.isEmpty()) {
   stk.push(input.charAt(i));
} else if(stk.peek()=='{') {
   stk.pop();
} else if(stk.peek()=='}') {
    stk.push(input.charAt(i));
}
```

*On a different note, I think the result cannot be greater than 2. It either has to be 0 or 2.*

Comment: yeah...i had made above changes..now the output is 0.i think output should be 2.Neither 0 nor greater than 2...i think after making above changes there is still some errors...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. For input `}{`, I'm getting output as 2 as the stack will have both `}` and `{`

Comment: can you able to give your code so that i can understand where is the problem in my code!!

Comment: Here you go - [Ideone code](https://ideone.com/53w5fI)